# Loop through an xml and add to a gridview

Tags: xml, vb.net, gridview

I'm trying to loop through an xml and out put the nodes into a gridview.

this is the code I'm using:

```
Dim iCustomer As XPathNodeIterator = nav.Select(nav.Compile("//Content"))
While iCustomer.MoveNext() ' Loop through all customer nodes
    ' NOW you can get those child nodes
    Dim Title As XPathNodeIterator = iCustomer.Current.SelectChildren("Title", "")
    Dim iName As XPathNodeIterator = iCustomer.Current.SelectChildren("QuickLink", "")
    Dim iContact As XPathNodeIterator = iCustomer.Current.SelectChildren("Teaser", "")

    If Title.Count <> 0 Then ' If a node is found....
        ' You *might* have to call iListID.MoveNext() here
        Title.MoveNext()
        NewRow("Content_Title") = Title.Current.Value
        ' ListID = iListID.Current.Value ' ... set the value to the string
    End If
    ' Do the above for each other value
End While
```

I only get the last node added, how can I output all the matching nodes.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest ways would be to populate a table in memory with the rows you want from thee xml data and then just bind it to the gridview. I have done this many times - very fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code:

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim dr As DataRow
Dim iCustomer As XPathNodeIterator = nav.Select(nav.Compile("//Content"))
While iCustomer.MoveNext() ' Loop through all customer nodes
' NOW you can get those child nodes

Dim Title As XPathNodeIterator = iCustomer.Current.SelectChildren("Title", "")
Dim iName As XPathNodeIterator = iCustomer.Current.SelectChildren("QuickLink", "")
Dim iContact As XPathNodeIterator = iCustomer.Current.SelectChildren("Teaser", "")

If Title.Count <> 0 Then ' If a node is found....
    ' You *might* have to call iListID.MoveNext() here
    Title.MoveNext()
    dr = dt.NewRow() 
    dr("Content_Title") = Title.Current.Value 
    ' ListID = iListID.Current.Value ' ... set the value to the string
    dt.Rows.Add(dr)
End If
' Do the above for each other value
End While

DataGrid.DataSource = dt
```